# Why can't selenium click on element?

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

This is my code to try and interact with whoscored.com. I've used selenium before and know that you have to click "agree" to cookie use before you can do anything else on the website. However, in this case,
selenium doesn't seem to be able to click on the "agree" button. Is it my code or the website that's the
issue?

The error I get is

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/2/Seasons/6829/Stages/15151/PlayerStatistics/England-Premier-League-2017-2018")

time.sleep(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='qc-cmp2-container']/div[@id='qc-cmp2-main']/div[@class='sc-dnqmqq dkDDgT qc-cmp-cleanslate']/div[@id='qc-cmp2-ui']/div[@class='qc-cmp2-footer qc-cmp2-footer-overlay qc-cmp2-footer-scrolled']/div[@class='qc-cmp2-summary-buttons']/button[@class='sc-bwzfXH kTIxrL']").click()
```

Comment: I don't see agree button in this page. Are you sure?

Comment: My solution for another page was to install an adblock extension. I used the firefox driver though, so I don't know how you do that with the chrome driver.

Comment: try it in incognito, because you may have already been on this website before

Comment: As an aside, use `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` *once* at the very beginning instead of the wasteful `time.sleep(10)`.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me finding with a simpler xpath

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(., 'Agree')]").click()
```

`//button` find all the nodes that are button tags
and `[contains(., 'Agree']` find all the nodes which inner text contains the sub-string "Agree"

Comment: Because the class names that you use are intended to be dynamically modified  i suspect. It is usually wrong to rely to find element on non-understandable labels like `sc-dnqmqq dkDDgT qc-cmp-cleanslate`

Answer (score 0):

I had such a problem and I've found out this code always works better than 'click()' method even if the element is not interactable. check it out

```
yourElement = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//button[@class='sc-bwzfXH kTIxrL']")    
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", "yourElement")
```

wish it would help you